# can not create column family at cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra

I created a multi-node cluster of cassandra: node0 and node1 (cassandra version 1.1.1), then I used cassandra-cli connect to node0 and create a column family. The info of node0 is ok, but it throw an exception at node1 like this:

```
    ERROR 18:22:48,486 Exception in thread Thread[MigrationStage:1,5,main]
    org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.MarshalException: invalid UTF8 bytes 4fd5c745
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type.getString(UTF8Type.java:56)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.ColumnIdentifier.(ColumnIdentifier.java:47)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.CFDefinition.getKeyId(CFDefinition.java:125)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.CFDefinition.(CFDefinition.java:59)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.updateCfDef(CFMetaData.java:1303)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.keyAlias(CFMetaData.java:224)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.fromSchemaNoColumns(CFMetaData.java:1187)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.fromSchema(CFMetaData.java:1215)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.KSMetaData.deserializeColumnFamilies(KSMetaData.java:291)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTable.mergeColumnFamilies(DefsTable.java:396)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTable.mergeSchema(DefsTable.java:271)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefsTable.mergeRemoteSchema(DefsTable.java:249)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.DefinitionsUpdateVerbHandler$1.runMayThrow(DefinitionsUpdateVerbHandler.java:48)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

then i store data into the column family at node0, i can get the data at node0, and node1 say the column family not found. after i restart node1, i can get the data at node1 like node0.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: A complete exception stack trace will be more helpful to debug this issue.May be before restarting node1 it was not responsive and the schema that you had created was not replicated on this node. After restarting it may have actually become responsive and you are getting correct results.

Comment: i thank node1 was recover data from the log. if i delete the commitlog before i restart node1, i can not start node1 and throw exception: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.MarshalException: invalid UTF8 bytes 4fd5c5c2

Comment: previously i created CF by command "create column family Users;", now i create CF by "create column family Users with comparator=UTF8Type and key_validation_class=UTF8Type;" and it seem ok

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug fixed in the soon-to-be-released 1.1.2 version: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4307.  If you want to test the fix, you can pull the `trunk` branch from Apache's git repo.